# Typing a general query wrapper function correctly to use with useQuery

Tags: typescript, react-query

The docs mention how query keys passed by React Query's `useQuery` function [can be used as a way of passing parameters to the query function](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#query-function-variables). Based on this I made a general higher-ordered function that unwraps the parameters from the query key and passes it on to the underlying function:

```
function createTypedWrapper<P, R>(queryFunction: (params: P) => Promise<R>) {

  // return function ({ queryKey }: QueryFunctionContext<string | readonly unknown[]>) {
  // return function ({ queryKey }: QueryFunctionContext<string | readonly P[]>) {
  // return function ({ queryKey }: QueryFunctionContext<string |  P[]>) {

  return function ({ queryKey }:any) { // <-- the `any` is the issue here
    const [, params] = queryKey;
    return queryFunction(params as P);
  };
}
```

I can then use it like

```
const {data} = useQuery(["dashboard", { date: currentDay }], createTypedWrapper(getDashboardEvents));
```

The only issue with this function is that I want it to understand that the `queryKey` should only have the parameters of type `P` of the wrapped function. This is typed internally as `string | unknown []` and if I change the function definition to basically say that `queryKey` is `[string, P]` I get errors like `(string | { date: string; })[]' is not assignable to type '{ date: string; }[]`.

This is understandable: `string` cannot be mapped to an array. But is what I want achievable?